# How to automate testing on Google mobile app with appium on iOS simulator?

Tags: iphone, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I want to automate Google app testing using appium on iPhone. The thing is, I use android device, so no physical iPhone device available with me.
Please let me know how I can test Google app on appium using iPhone simulator?

Comment: This question can easily be answered by Google or reading the most basic documentation on the technologies you're attempting to use. By asking, you've demonstrated you've not attempted to seek the answer for yourself, which is frowned upon on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Mac with [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Please review the Appium documentation as this is one of the first steps required in [setting up the XCUITest driver](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest.md).

Comment: I am arranging Mac with latest Xcode, I also know how to automate ios app when .ipa or .app file is provided since I worked on couple of projects for the same. But I am not aware how to automate Google mobile app on iOS since there is no .ipa file neither I am getting bundleID or the main question is how to install Google app on iOS simulator since I dont have iPhone.

Comment: Ah, ok, that wasn't too clear. This is not possible. You would need to build the app yourself or have an IPA delivered too you with the appropriate signing and certs.